# Using OpenFIleDialog to get path for word document in C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I'm trying to use OpendFileDialog to get the path to be passed to word application instance. This is my code so far. It is telling me 'Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?

This is my code. Thanks.

```
OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = @"All Files|*.*";

        if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = null;       

        object fileName = "filePath";

        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        document = App.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your currently setting your `fileName` to `"filePath"` as a string not to the actual path. You will notice in your code you are setting your `filePath` variable within the `if` scope which is only scoped to the `if` statement.

```
OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = @"All Files|*.*";
    object fileName = "";
    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(OpenFileDialog1.FileName);
    }

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = null;       



    object missing = System.Type.Missing;
    document = App.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                              ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

You will notice the change is moving the `fileName` assignment before the `if` scope and then setting the `fileName` value to the File from the OpenFileDialog. This is then passed to the interop methods. My suggestion will be to set a breakpoint on the `object fileName = ""` line and check your variable assignments.

I will add that you should be changing your code it ensure if the result of your OpenFile dialog IS NOT OK then you should add a return statement or through another pattern to ensure you are not executing code that will fail as the user has cancelled or closed the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for responding. It worked!! Do you mind telling me how to save to local directory? Thanks.